# Gridview RowUpdating NewValues cannot save null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been struggling for a while with this problem. In my GridView I am trying to set specific values for columns that are contained in an EntityDataSource. In my model I specifically set the nullable property to true and the column in the database is Nullable, but when I try to save a null value, the system will not save it. Here are snippets of my code:

entityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edServiceKeys" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=APIEntities" DefaultContainerName="APIEntities" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="ServiceKeys"></asp:EntityDataSource>
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dvServiceKeys" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="ServiceKeyId" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="edServiceKeys" OnRowDataBound="dvServiceKeys_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="dvServiceKeys_RowUpdating">
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="Key" SortExpression="Key" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CreditUnionId" SortExpression="CreditUnionId">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCreditUnionId" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="edCreditUnions" DataTextField="Credit_Union_Name" DataValueField="Credit_Union_ID">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="None"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCreditUnionId" Value='<%# Eval("CreditUnionId") %>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstRoCreditUnionId" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="edCreditUnions" DataTextField="Credit_Union_Name" DataValueField="Credit_Union_ID" Enabled="False">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="None"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRoCreditUnionId" Value='<%# Eval("CreditUnionId") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Central_ID" SortExpression="Central_ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCentralId" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="edCentralIds" DataTextField="Central_Name" DataValueField="Central_ID">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="None"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCentralId" Value='<%# Eval("Central_ID") %>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstRoCentralId" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="edCentralIds" DataTextField="Central_Name" DataValueField="Central_ID" Enabled="false">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="None"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRoCentralId" Value='<%# Eval("Central_ID") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="DingFree" HeaderText="DingFree" SortExpression="DingFree" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

listener:

```
protected void dvServiceKeys_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = dvServiceKeys.EditIndex;
        GridViewRow row = dvServiceKeys.Rows[index];
        DropDownList creditUnion = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("lstCreditUnionId");
        DropDownList central = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("lstCentralId");

        if (creditUnion.SelectedValue == "-1")
            e.NewValues["CreditUnionId"] = null;
        else
            e.NewValues["CreditUnionId"] = creditUnion.SelectedValue;

        if (central.SelectedValue == "-1")
            e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = null;
        else
            e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = central.SelectedValue;
    }
```

I've tried setting the NewValues to the following:

```
e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = null;
e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = dbNull.Value;
e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = "";
e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = string.empty;

int? nullInt = null;
e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = nullInt;

Nullable<Int32> nullInt = null;
e.NewValues["Central_ID"] = nullInt;
```

I am able to save any value to that column EXCEPT for null. This is a column of type int in the database, or type int? in the code. Also, this is a duplicate question to

[How to set field values equal to null in RowUpdating(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447015/how-to-set-field-values-equal-to-null-in-rowupdating)

but unfortunately his solution was not my solution. I've found others, but everyone seems to have found a simple solution, but for my case, none of the solutions seemed to work.

Comment: what the data type of Central_ID? is it nullable?

Comment: Yup, they're all nullable ints. So I guess .NET declaration would be int?.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? If you are already sure you are using int? throughout the code, and the database field is nullable, then there isn't much else to check that I can think of. Perhaps the exception message will offer more clues to someone looking at this. Also, is it bombing when setting the value to null, or when actually saving back to the database?

Comment: Also, if you are not getting a error, but rather it's just not updating to Null, but retaining the old value, that sounds like something isn't bound correctly. See this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/143485/Gridview_RowUpdating-not-setting-null-to-newvalue